# pig latin - not showing the right record numbers

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I have written a `pig script` for `wordcount` which works fine. I could see the results from pig script in my output directory in hdfs. But towards the end of my console, I see the following:

```
Success!

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTIme  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_local1695568121_0002    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   words_sorted    SAMPLER 
job_local2103470491_0003    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   words_sorted    ORDER_BY    /output/result_pig,
job_local696057848_0001 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   book,words,words_agg,words_grouped  GROUP_BY,COMBINER   

Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records from: "/data/pg5000.txt"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "/output/result_pig"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local696057848_0001 ->  job_local1695568121_0002,
job_local1695568121_0002    ->  job_local2103470491_0003,
job_local2103470491_0003


2014-07-01 14:10:35,241 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

As you can see, the job is success. but not the `Input(s)` and `output(s)`. Both of the them say `successfully read/stored 0 records` and the counter values are all 0.
why the value is zero. These should not be zero.

I am using `hadoop2.2 and pig-0.12`

Here is the script:

```
book = load '/data/pg5000.txt' using PigStorage() as (lines:chararray);
words = foreach book generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(lines)) as word;
words_grouped = group words by word;
words_agg = foreach words_grouped generate group as word, COUNT(words);
words_sorted = ORDER words_agg BY $1 DESC;
STORE words_sorted into '/output/result_pig' using PigStorage(':','-schema');
```

NOTE: my data is present in `/data/pg5000.txt` and not in default directory which is `/usr/name/data/pg5000.txt`

EDIT: here is the output of printing my file to console

```
hadoop fs -cat /data/pg5000.txt | head -10
The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Notebooks of Leonardo Da Vinci, Complete
by Leonardo Da Vinci
(#3 in our series by Leonardo Da Vinci)

Copyright laws are changing all over the world. Be sure to check the
copyright laws for your country before downloading or redistributing
this or any other Project Gutenberg eBook.

This header should be the first thing seen when viewing this Project
Gutenberg file.  Please do not remove it.  Do not change or edit the
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

Comment: Please share the script

Comment: @RajnishG: added script above

Comment: can you do a `hadoop fs -tail /data/pg5000.txt` just to verify

Comment: @sayandasgupta: I have pasted above the contents

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the following line

```
book = load '/data/pg5000.txt' using PigStorage() as (lines:chararray);
```

to

```
book = load '/data/pg5000.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (lines:chararray);
```

I am assuming the delimiter as comma here use the one which is used to separate the records in your file. This will solve the issue

Also note --

If no argument is provided, PigStorage will assume tab-delimited format. If a delimiter argument is provided, it must be a single-byte character; any literal (eg: 'a', '|'), known escape character (eg: '\t', '\r') is a valid delimiter.